# Made made snana ritual

Tags: customs, bath

As described in this [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Made_Made_Snana) post, made made snana involves rolling over the banana leaves after eating.

Is there any scriptural validity (apart from the fact that it's now a "custom") for such a bath?

Normally after eating the leaves are considered unclean. What justifications are there for such a snana or against it(because it's impure/unclean)?

The question is only about the banana leaf part and not about holy bath later in the river.